# Is finding a solution harder than verifying a solution?

Tags: ds.algorithms, complexity-classes

Is there any known problem in Comp science where determinisitically finding a "non-trivial" solution to that problem is asymptotically easier than verifying a solution?

Comment: It depends what exactly you mean. There are many examples where a simple randomized algorithm succeeds with high probability but we do not know any way to verify that the algorithm has succeeded. For example a random Gaussian matrix satisfies the RIP property with high probability but we do not know an efficient algorithm to test for this property.

Comment: No I mean, deterministically... I will go and update it.
and are they quite common in literature?
Dont they seem counter-intuitive.

Comment: What about: *"Given a positive integer $n$, find a divisor $d$ of $n$."* Finding a solution (for instance the divisor $d=1$) can be trivially done in constant time $O(1)$, without even looking at the input. But for verifying that some arbitrary integer $d$ is indeed a divisor of $n$, one has to read the input and hence needs at least $\Omega(\log n)$ time.

Comment: Any NP problem outside P. Actually, depending on what exactly you mean by “asymptotically easier”, any NP problem outside coNLOGTIME (plenty of those are known, unconditionally).

Comment: The answer has to be no if you have the same deterministic algorithm that was used to generate the solution you're considering, as one can always just run that algorithm, see that you get the same answer, and return. The runtime is asymptotically identical. I think the only way to get around this would be tricks like Gamow's - problems that include a trivial solution, but other more interesting solutions exist.

Comment: Okay, i will edit the question to say "non-trivial" solutions, otherwise question wont make sense.

Emil and artimis are giving contradicting answers...
I request both of u read the question clearly,

Comment: How do you define ​ "non-trivial" ​ for your question? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer- Please read the comments, u will get the context.

Comment: I have now read the comments and get the context, but still lack an answer to my question. ​ ​

Comment: Does FPTAS for permanent work?

Answer (score 4):

Let us consider the following problem:

- Instance: A Turing machine $M$. A word $w$.
- Feasible solutions: (i) The word $ww$. (ii) The word $w$, in case $M$ accepts $w$.

(1) Now finding a solution is very easy: Simply output the word $ww$ in linear time.
(2) On the other hand, deciding whether the word $w$ is a feasible solution for a given instance is an undecidable problem.